# Running ethernet cable between drywall and cement foundation, and repairing drywall afterwards

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall

I am installing a new floor in a basement addition (addition was done sometime in the 2000s), and as part of that, wanted to run ethernet cables as well.  The floor is going to be 1" of EPS foam, and then two layers of 15/32 plywood.  I'm using the guidelines provided by the BuildingScience corporation.  Unfortunately, the ceiling is finished, and I'm not going to be able to replace it for the next few years, so I was planning on running 3/4" ENT conduit underneath the plywood against the walls, and fishing ethernet through there.  There are, for reasons I'm unclear on, several boxes already installed with no wiring going to them, so I figured I could just fish the cables up from the conduit.

So I was cutting through the drywall along the base of the wall so I'd have a path, and discovered not the plywood that I was expecting, but concrete.  I'm not sure if that's the foundation of the original house, or what.  And while I could in theory cut into it, I don't know of any reason to do so.  Instead, I'm planning on just running the ethernet up a channel from the floor (I'll install a low profile box under the new floor, instead of in the wall as I was planning to before).

So, questions are:  1)  Is this a horrible idea, for some reason that's not occurring to me?

2)  After running the cables, how do I patch the channel in the wall?  I won't be able to use a drywall patch, as the patch would be too thick.  I'm thinking about taking a piece of drywall of the appropriate size, shaving down the gypsum, and attaching it using the hammock method.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not a horrible idea and should be fine.
if it was power you would need a nail plate over the wire but data doesn’t even need an electrical box.

I usually purchase metal rings that hold the cover plate , you will find most cable installed this way where they punch a hole through the wall, go inside find the hole and cut the opening slip the plate in , much easier than trying to fish the cable through a hole in the old work box.

These devices are called drywall brackets, mud rings, low voltage mounting brackets. Some are metal some are plastic they range in price from .50 to ~6$

I bought a case a while back of single gang sw-wbf-1 they were maybe .30 in bulk (100 count) some come with screws some don’t but drywall screws work just fine to anchor them in the Sheetrock.

You may want to cut a small Chanel in the Sheetrock to allow enough space for the wire as it looks like it is attached directly to the foundation.

Comment: Right, I have low-voltage mounting brackets already, which I'd planned on using.  I'm just trying to make pulling the cables as easy as possible, and possibly making things future-proof, so I could pull additional cables in the future.  Thanks!